# Alert Message Button

Tags: javascript, alert

Trying to get the button called, "check" to show the var result from the answer prompt1 function.  For whatever reason when I run the code nothing happens when the button is clicked.  I know the calculation is right because, when I set the answer button to give the intended alert, it works properly.  How do I get the second button to display my results entered?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <!--
        Name: Dakota Trumbull
        Date:
        Class:
        Purpose:
    -->
    <title>Math Test</title>





</head>

<body>

    <h1>Simple Math Test</h1>

    <p>Q1: 5 + 9 = ??</p>
        <button id = "Q1A" onclick = "answerPrompt1()">Answer</button>
        <button id = "Q1C" onclick ="showResult()">Check</button>

    <p></p>

    <p>Q2:  4 * 6 = ??</p>
        <button id = "Q2A">Answer</button>
        <button id = "Q2C">Check</button>

    <p></p>

    <p>Q3: 25 - 14 = ??</p>
        <button id = "Q3A">Answer</button>
        <button id = "Q3C">Check</button>

    <p></p>

    <p>Q4: 48 / 3 = ??</p>
        <button id = "Q4A">Answer</button>
        <button id = "Q4C">Check</button>

    <p></p>

    <p>Q5: 26 % 6 = ??</p>
        <button id = "Q5A">Answer</button>
        <button id = "Q5C">Check</button>

</body>

<script>



    //Q1


    function answerPrompt1()
    {
         var answer1 = prompt("Enter your answer: ");
         var convertedNum1 = parseInt(answer1, 10);
         var result = (convertedNum1 == 14)? "You're right!" :
            "Sorry, that's incorrect.";
    }
    function showResult()
    {
        alert(result);
    }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Adding the source of answerPrompt1 and showResult might help us to help you

Comment: Please set this up as a snippet or jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is declared in `answerPrompt1`, which gives it local scope (i.e.  it isn't visible outside that function).  move the declaration to just before the function:

```js
var result = "You have not given an answer yet";
function answerPrompt1()
{
     var answer1 = prompt("Enter your answer: ");
     var convertedNum1 = parseInt(answer1, 10);
     result = (convertedNum1 == 14)? "You're right!" :
        "Sorry, that's incorrect.";
}
function showResult()
{
    alert(result);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Simple Math Test</h1>
    <p>Q1: 5 + 9 = ??</p>
        <button id = "Q1A" onclick = "answerPrompt1()">Answer</button>
        <button id = "Q1C" onclick ="showResult()">Check</button>
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `result` variable in a way that it can be accessible to both functions  `answerPrompt1()` and `showResult()` You can have a clear understanding about how javascript scope works from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

```
var result = "You have not given an answer yet"; //this variable is accessible to both functions
function answerPrompt1()
{
     var answer1 = prompt("Enter your answer: "); //this variable only accessible inside the function answerPrompt1()
     var convertedNum1 = parseInt(answer1, 10);
     result = (convertedNum1 == 14)? "You're right!" :
        "Sorry, that's incorrect.";
}
function showResult()
{
    alert(result);
}
```